# Rails normalize csv file data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, database-normalization

I'm trying to import a tsv (tab separated data) file into my database only it's not formatted properly. The columns `price` and `count` are only separated by a space (with the exception of the header line) and the values are both placed into the `price` key, moving all the data into the wrong key value pairs.

tsv file:

```
purchaser name  item description    price   count   merchant address    merchant name
Alice Bob   $10 off $20 of food 10.0 2   987 Fake St     Bob's Pizza
Example Name    $30 of awesome for $10  10.0 5   456 Unreal Rd   Tom's Awesome Shop
Name Three  $20 Sneakers for $5 5.0    1     123 Fake St     Sneaker Store Emporium
John Williams   $20 Sneakers for $5 5.0    4     123 Fake St     Sneaker Store Emporium
```

in `/models/purchase.rb`:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validates :item_price, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, :headers => true,
                       :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')},
                       :col_sep => "\t"
                       ) do |row|
                      # debugger
                      purchase_hash = row.to_hash
      Purchase.create!(purchase_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

If i import the file and comment in the debugger in the model and then type `row` it returns:

`#<CSV::Row "purchaser_name":"Alice Bob" "item_description":"$10 off $20 of food" "price":"10.0 2" "count":" 987 Fake St" "merchant_address":" Bob's Pizza" "merchant_name":nil>`

`row.inspect` returns:

`"#<CSV::Row \"purchaser_name\":\"Alice Bob\" \"item_description\":\"$10 off $20 of food\" \"price\":\"10.0 2\" \"count\":\" 987 Fake St\" \"merchant_address\":\" Bob's Pizza\" \"merchant_name\":nil>"`

As you can see the `price` (10.0) and `count` (2) have been squished into the same value because they were not tab separated in the file.

`db/schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160601205154) do

  create_table "purchases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "purchaser_name"
    t.string   "item_description"
    t.string   "price"
    t.string   "count"
    t.string   "merchant_address"
    t.string   "merchant_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

end
```

I originally had `price` as a Decimal datatype and `count` as an Integer but switched them back to String to try to find a solution. I can change them back if it will help (and would prefer to change them back if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is twofold. First, define a converter that will split the field into two parts (and convert it to numbers in the process) during parsing:

```
CONVERTER_SPLIT_PRICE_COUNT = lambda do |value, info|
  next value unless info.header == "price"
  price, count = value.split
  [ price.to_f, count.to_i ]
end
```

This turns the `price` field into an array, e.g. `"10.0 2"` becomes `[10.0, 2]`.

Second, define a method that, after parsing, will fix the misplaced value and return a correct Hash:

```
def row_to_hash_fixing_price_count(row)
  row.headers.zip(row.fields.flatten).to_h
end
```

The above flattens the price/count array into its parent array (the rest of the row) and then zips it up with the headers array. Since there are now more fields than headers the extra `nil` at the end is dropped.

You'll use them like this:

```
csv_opts = {
  headers: true,
  col_sep: "\t",
  header_converters: ->(h) { h.downcase.tr(" ", "_") },
  converters: CONVERTER_SPLIT_PRICE_COUNT
}

data_out = CSV.new(data, csv_opts).map do |row|
  row_to_hash_fixing_price_count(row)
end
# => [ { "purchaser_name" => "Alice Bob",
#        "item_description" => "$10 off $20 of food",
#        "price" => 10.0,
#        "count" => 2,
#        "merchant_address" => "987 Fake St",
#        "merchant_name" => "Bob's Pizza"
#      },
#      # ...
#    ]
```

You can see it in action here: http://ideone.com/08wTPT

P.S. Consider creating records in bulk instead of one at a time. Given the above you could just do `Purchase.create!(data_out)` since [`create!` accepts an array of hashes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create).

Answer (score 0):

you could try shifting merchant_address and merchant_name values then split the squished price and count fileds by a space and assing the two values to price and count:

```
purchase_hash = row.to_hash
purchase_hash[:merchant_name] = purchase_hash[:merchant_address]
purchase_hash[:merchant_address] = purchase_hash[:count]
splitted_price_count = purchase_hash[:price].split(" ")
purchase_hash[:price] = splitted_price_count.first
purchase_hash[:count] = splitted_price_count.last
Purchase.create!(purchase_hash)
```